# How to load angular module before loading controller using RequireJs, Jasmine, Karma

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, karma-runner

I'm trying to write unit test for angular app, using RequireJs, Jasmine, Karma. At this moment I get this error:

> "Module 'coreModule' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument."

When I run my app, everything is Ok, a problem is occurs only when I run unit tests.

This is my "coreModules" code which creates new angular module and load all controllers:

```
define(['app/modules/core/controllerReferences'], function(references) {

    var coreModule = angular.module('coreModule', []);

    require(references, function() {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['coreModule']);
    });
});
```

And here is code of my homeController:

```
define(['angular'], function() {

    angular.module('coreModule')
        .controller('homeController', function($scope) {
            $scope.title = "Hello World";
    });
});
```

As I mentioned earlier, I'm trying to write simple unit test but I can't load 'homeController' because I get above error.

```
define(['coreModule','angularMocks', 'app/modules/core/controllers/homeController'], function() {

   describe('homeController test.', function() {

   });
});
```

I don't know why, because I load 'coreModule' before 'homeController'. I tried to load 'homeController' by `require(['path/homeController'], function(){})`, then I don't get any error but callback function in require is not called. Also I add:

```
require(['coreModule'], function() {
  console.log('Load core module.');
});
```

to my test-main.js to initialize 'coreModule'.